# Yii login user type not getting write

Tags: php, database, yii, filewriter

i just made a login with yii. in my login table theres a "usertype" coloumn so in order to check whether its working fine i have put a file writer inside the code, but its not getting write(forget about the user type not even a string) everytime the code runs its empty. following is code

components/useridentity

```
<?php

class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity

{
    private $_id;

public function authenticate()
{


            $user = Trackaccountusers::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));

            if ($user===null) { // No user found!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            } else if ($user->password !== ($this->password) ) { // Invalid password!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            } else { // Okay!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            // Store the role in a session:
            $this->setState('usertype', $user->usertype);
            $file = "log.txt";
            $write = ("time_s ".$user->usertype."\n");//
            file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
            //$this->_id = $user->id;
            }
            return !$this->errorCode;

}
            public function getId()
            {
            return $this->_id;
            }
```

}

Comment: do u have sufficient permission to create file in component directory?

Comment: what's the file system (linux/windows/other) as the file_put_contents cannot be trusted, the best way is still to use fopen with the a+ flag and make sure it is locked so no other process can use it (if in windows you have the file open somehow somewhere and php tries file_put_contents it will just fail)#

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem occurs because of two reason.

1. Check you have write permission to component directory. You can set it using `chmod -R +x components`
2. Check you have apache/ngnix user owner to component directory. You can set it using `chown -R www:data:www:data components`
3. Use below code in your views/controllers to check Yii State **(usertype)** is set or not

   ```
   $usertype = isset(Yii::app()->user->usertype) ? Yii::app()->user->usertype : '';
   ```

**Note:** You don't have to write file to check Yii user State. Instead of writing a file use `error_log("usertype = $usertype")` or print the State in view.